# What are the FAA/CS requirements for rubber chocks?

Tags: airport, faa, equipment, airport-operations

What are the FAA/CS requirements for rubber chocks? Do they include material, manufacturing processes, etc.?

Answer (score 4):

I could not find FAA requirements; however, there is an industry standard: [**SAE J348**](https://www.sae.org/standards/content/j348_196807/) (the details are behind a paywall).

A 1993 *flightsafety.org* [publication](https://flightsafety.org/amb/amb_jan-feb93.pdf) emphasizes that chock placement and design are essential, for example:

> The chock’s height is very important and it depends on the size of wheel to be restrained. For heavy transport aircraft, a six-inch (15.2 cm) height for wooden or rubber chocks is effective in general ramp usage. For restraining an aircraft during ground run-up operations, most operators use larger, fabricated steel chocks of greater height, sometimes as much as 12 or 15 inches (30.5 or 38.1 cm).

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen any FAA requirements on chocks in my reading of the Federal Aviation Regulations (FAR) or the Airmen Information Manual (AIM).  I used to use some pieces of triangular shaped wood in front & in back of the main landing gear wheels.